# Reptyr: How to send process back to the background

Tags: linux

I'm using reptyr to bring a background process to a new terminal.

The description says reptyr should recognize ctrl+z, but it doesn't.

I'm wondering how I can set the process I just brought to the terminal, back to the background.

What I had in mind was:

```
reptyr <processid>
(ctrl+z)
bg
disown
```

Answer (score 0):

on the other console you can run:

```
nohup ./reptyr $PID_OF_PREVOUS_REPTYL_COMMAND &> /dev/null &
```

$PID_OF_PREVOUS_REPTYL_COMMAND you can retrieve from `ps fx` command